# openldap master/slave replication configuration return TLS error from slave

Tags: ssl, openldap, replication

I am trying to add a TLS secured replication between a master and a slave ldap server. The replication without TLS work well.

I encounter this error from the slave : `slapd_client_connect: URI=ldap://master.domain.com Error, ldap_start_tls failed (-11)`

Here is my configuration :

```
----- Master -----
/etc/ldap/ldap.conf
  URI            ldap://master.domain.com/
  TLS_CACERT     /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
  TLS_REQCERT    demand

/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
  olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/master-key.pem
  olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/master-cert.pem
```

```
----- Slave -----
/etc/ldap/ldap.conf
  URI            ldap://slave.domain.com/
  TLS_CACERT     /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
  TLS_REQCERT    demand

/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
  olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/slave-key.pem
  olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/slave-cert.pem

/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase{1}mdb.ldif
  olcSyncrepl: rid=001, provider=ldap://master.domain.com binddn="cn=readonly,ou=users,dc=master,dc=domain,dc=com" bindmethod=simple credentials="mypass" searchbase="dc=master,dc=domain,dc=com" type=refreshAndPersist timeout=0 network-timeout=0 retry="60 +" starttls=critical tls_reqcert=demand
```

This is what I already checked / tryed :

- The certificates on both server are owned by the user `openldap`
- The fingerprint of cacert.pem on both server are the same
- The expiration date of the certificates are good
- The cn in the cacert.pem is equal to the cn of the master server
- The slave can use the following command to search on the master : `ldapsearch -ZZ -x -H master.domain.com -b "ou=groups,dc=master,dc=domain,dc=com"`
- Changing the slave `olcTLS` value to use the master certificates
- Using `ldaps://` instead of `ldap:// + starttls` (`ldapsearch -ZZ -H ldaps://` was working)

After some research on internet, it often talk about the CA certificate (either the cn in it, the owner of the file, ...) but I already checked theses cases.

Do you have an idea where the problem come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what I read on multiple tutorials, we need to configure the CA file in the olcTLS variables even if we are using self-signed certificate.

I belive the `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` file is not read as OpenLDAP now work with the slapd.d folder with a "new" system of configuration.

This is the configuration I endend up doing to activate TLS for the master/slave replication :

```
----- Master -----
/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
  olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
  olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/master-key.pem
  olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/master-cert.pem
```

```
----- Slave -----
/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
  olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
  olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/slave-key.pem
  olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/slave-cert.pem
```

Note :

- The slave certificate need to have it's own `cn` in it
- If you encounter the `mods check (objectClass: value #2 invalid per syntax)` error, the slave miss some schema loaded on the master